# MS Office URL-authentication information missing

Tags: .net, ms-office, webdav, .net-4.8, ithit-webdav-server

I want to avoid login dailog box when on opening a word document using WebDavServer.

The official documentation says I can do it like this
"implement URL-authentication. Your URLs will look like http://server/[SessionID1234567890]/path/file.docx"

https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only

So what does that mean I do not have any authentication at Backend of my .net app and just send the sessionID. That's it. but it does not work.

I already had MS-OFBA with OIDC but I disabled it to test this. Please point me towards right resource.

Official website hardly has any detailed information (Even their official answers on SO)

I already had MS-OFBA with OIDC but I disabled it to test this.

```
public static void MsOfbaConfiguration(this IAppBuilder app, string baseUrl)
    {
        app.Use(async (owinContext, next) =>
        {
            var request = owinContext.Request;
            var response = owinContext.Response;

            const string authenticatedCallback = "/authenticated";
            const string login = "/login";

            var returnUrl = $"{baseUrl}{authenticatedCallback}";

            var isAuthenticated = request.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;

            switch (request.Method)
            {
                case "GET" when request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/ping")):
                    await response.WriteAsync($"\"{baseUrl.Split('/').Last()} pong\"").ConfigureAwait(false);
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    return;
                case "OPTIONS" when request.Headers.Get("User-Agent").Contains("Office") && !isAuthenticated:
                    var loginUrl = $"{baseUrl}{login}";
                    response.Headers["X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_REQUIRED"] = $"{loginUrl}?returnUrl={returnUrl}";
                    response.Headers["X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_RETURN_URL"] = returnUrl;
                    response.Headers["X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_DIALOG_SIZE"] = "800x600";
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                    return;
                case "GET" when request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString(login)) && isAuthenticated:
                    response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                    return;
                case "GET" when request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString(authenticatedCallback)):
                    return;
                default:
                    await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    public static IAppBuilder UseOpenIdConnectAuthConfiguration(this IAppBuilder app, string baseUrl)
    {
        var optionsMonitor = GlobalServiceProvider.ServiceProvider.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<OidcOptions>>();
        var oidcOptions = optionsMonitor.Get(OidcOptions.Contexts.PortalStartup);

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = oidcOptions.Authority,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            ClientId = oidcOptions.ClientId,
            RedirectUri = $"{baseUrl}signin",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            ResponseType = "code",
            Scope = oidcOptions.Scope,
            RedeemCode = true,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = $"{baseUrl}logout",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                .WithUserProfile()
                .WithFailureControl(),
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SaveTokens = true,
        });
        return app;
    }

    public static OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications WithFailureControl(this OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications notifications)
    {
        _ = notifications ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(notifications));

        notifications.AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed;

        return notifications;
    }

    private static Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> arg)
    {
        arg.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        arg.HandleResponse();
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```